# Undelete diagram in enterprise architect EA

Tags: diagram, enterprise, enterprise-architect

How can I retrieve my diagram that I deleted by mistake in enterprise Architect ? I search in google but I don't find any way to retrieve the diagram.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use your backup.

If you have none then you are out of luck.